# My application is deployed in Websphere Application server

Tags: java, websphere, relative-path

My application is deployed in Websphere Application server in the path

> /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/Node01/MyApplication.ear`

All the class files are placed in folder `/output/Sharelib/Common`. In the application I have a module which would accept user input and generate an xml file and it should be placed in the path `/output/Sharelib/a1/a2/a3`. If I give

> File file1=new File("output/sharelib/Common");

the file is getting placed in `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/output/sharelib/a1/a2/a3`. How to place the file in `/outptu/sharelib/a1/a2/a3`.

Comment: You mean to say, there is a folder `/output` at the same level as `/usr` and you need to place it in that? Because, looking at the question  this is being placed in what you want but the root is considered as `installedApps`. You can try `File("./output/sharelib/Common")`

Comment: @Hrishikesh yes there is a folder /output at the same level as /usr level and I need to place the file in that path using java.

Comment: The path in your code is clearly relative. Did you try an absolute path (one starting with a slash)?